# Searching performance in vectors vs set

Tags: c++, vector, set

After reading a few questions and answers that say the following:

> Look up in a set is asymptotically faster than in a vector. (Since a set is basically a binary search tree ). For the task at hand, set is faster than vector because it keeps its contents sorted and does a binary search to find a specified item, giving logarithmic complexity instead of linear complexity.

My question is - will searching for an element in a sorted vector using binary search take same time as searching an element in a set? If not, then what are the reason(s) behind the difference in the performance?

Comment: I think relative performance will depend on the particular implementations of `std::vector` and `std::set`, as well as the compiler used, and the optimization options of a particular compilation.

Comment: Thanks @Rapptz . So that should mean equivalent performance.

Comment: @Noob Equivalent *asymptotic* performance. Your question seems to be missing the point that these "performances" are asymptotic.

Comment: Related note: there are other reasonable implementations for ordered sets, such as skip lists. They don't have to be trees.

Comment: Thanks @juanchopanza. I'll be sure to note that.

Comment: I think you should measure the time on different platform and verify it. But I think vector should be better in performance due to many other factor(cache) over set under the scenario.

Comment: Thanks @MantoshKumar . Discarding any hardware related issues, logically should the performances be same ?

Comment: Sorted array *is* a representation of a perfectly balanced (assuming you always take the middle element of a range as the root of that sub-tree) binary search tree. So on purely logical level the question is meaningless. You need the implementation details to ask that question.

Comment: @Noob what do you mean by logical? It seems pretty logical that `vector` is faster. Even though asymptotically they are the same, you can't ignore hardware factors and constant multipliers if you do need to optimize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can keep the vector sorted, and use `std::lower_bound`,
searching is `O(lg(n))` for both.  With the caveat that
`std::vector` enjoys much better locality, and so on most
machines, will have a significantly lower constant factor.  It
may also result in more efficient memory use, due to less
fragmentation—this is particularly true if you know the
maximum size up front, and can use `std::vector<>::reserve`.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is unlikely you'll see much of a performance difference.

I've seen other performance related questions on Stack Overflow. There are a lot of really good material coming out these days around performance of the standard containers, especially with the speed and size of the caches we are now getting in the hardware.

Here is a video in which Herb Sutter goes into some detail about the performance of `std::vector`; http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661 Herb Sutter goes into some detail with very nice graphs, diagrams, explanations etc. from around the 23:30 mark and he picks up Bjarne's material at around the 46:00 mark.

Answer (score 2):

Both will have the same asymptotic performance as in a set is takes O(log(n)) time and when a vector is sorted and an element is searched using Binary Search - the time complexity shall again be O(log(n)).